# API keys when API calls contain sensitive data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-key, google-cloud-api-gateway

While I was reading the documentation for Google Cloud API gateway, I found this paragraph:

> Unlike credentials that use short-live tokens or signed requests, API keys are a part of the request and are therefore considered to be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks and therefore less secure. You can use API keys in addition to one of the authentication methods described below. **For security reasons, don't use API keys by themselves when API calls contain sensitive data.**
> https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method#api_keys

Could someone elaborate on the highlighed sentence? What exactly are the security reasons?

Answer (score 2):

Because API keys are bearer tokens and relatively easily obtained, if I get your API key, I can make API calls on your behalf and, if an API call that I can make, reveals sensitive information, then I've got that too.

I think one way to think about API keys is as unique identifiers but ones where knowledge of them isn't problematic. For example, like a telephone number. They (a) identify you but I'm going to expect to hear your voice when I answer to authenticate you; (b) people prefer not to broadcast their (cell)phone numbers.